# Which PyPy memory profiler is recommended?

Tags: memory-management, profiler, pypy

What tools can I use to monitor PyPy’s memory consumption?  It’s better if the tool is portable for various Python interpreters (CPython and PyPy) and versions (2.6 to 3.3).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I only know about one profiler, which is provided by python community itself, **memory profiler**.

You can download it using either pip or easy_install,

```
$ easy_install -U memory_profiler # pip install -U memory_profiler
```

**psutil** is recommended module to have with this profiler.

If you want to install it from source,

```
$ python setup.py install
```

The latest sources can be found on https://github.com/fabianp/memory_profiler.

Documentation, samples, API help can be found on https://pypi.python.org/pypi/memory_profiler.